# r: errors creating package with devtools & roxygen2

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I'm writing a package containing several functions to make running and evaluating models more streamlined.

I have a function that I'm going to make the first function within my package detailed with roxygen2 comments, which I can include into this write-up as an edit if necessary, but my issue is more with Package Creation.

I've created a separate `.R` file for the function and it lives within the `R` folder in within my package folder. I've run `R CMD build pkgname` and `R CMD INSTALL pkgname` successfully.

At the `document()` stage I run it (from console or whether in my terminal using `R -e 'library(devtools);document()'`, deleting the existing `NAMESPACE` file first) and I get the following error: `Try removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/ 3.5/Resources/library/00LOCK-pkgname`.

I've already seen the [issue posted here][1] and haven't had success after deleting the `00LOCK-pkgname` folder, for two reasons: when I run `document()`, even when it throws the above error, it doesn't stop running, it just keeps looping (that happens whether I run this in R or use the Terminal). Additionally, no matter how many times I delete the folder, it keeps re-appearing even though I've stopped running the function.

Any insight into why that error is being thrown and the `document()` function continually runs in a loop?

Comment: Any updates? I am curious as well.

Comment: @Mihai, I unfortunately have given up on the no longer use the command line for `document()` and `install()`. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I've found is in this blog post: [Hilary Parker R-Package Blog Post](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)

The steps I follow to document and install are as follows:

1. Within the project that contains my package, open a new R Script and run `setwd('..')`
2. Run `devtools::document()`
3. Run `devtools::install()`

This works for me when initially installing my package and also updating it.